# change product menu dropdown with checkbox and external product variable creation

Tags: plugins, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, templates

I'm trying to change the attributes menu of a variable product of woocomerce, I would like to change the dropdown menu into a checkbox menu, but there is nothing in the settings to change it.
Is it possible to modify the template in any way?
then another question, I have a variable product that 4 variations 3 of which are sold by my e-commerce and one not sold by me, the latter if selected should be sent to an external site.
Has anyone ever done something similar?